# How can I 'construct' in javascript a file received from a firebase cloud function and trigger automatically a download?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

With axios, I do a post request to a firebase cloud function and that function is sending me a file.
The file is taken from a FTP server. I am sure that the function works ok, because if I access it directly it shows me the right file.

I want to do the following: to send a request to the cloud function and in its response to trigger automatically a download.
I have the following code:

```
fileName = 'test.jpg' // fileName is received dynamically
this.$axios.post('https://the-url-of-cloud-function', {
          
  theFile: fileName
        
}).then((response) => {
  let uri = 'data:' + response.headers['content-type'] + ',' + response.data
          
  let elementToTriggerDownload = document.createElement('a')
          
  elementToTriggerDownload.href = uri
 
  elementToTriggerDownload.style = 'visibility:hidden'
          
  elementToTriggerDownload.download = fileName
  
  document.body.appendChild(elementToTriggerDownload)
          
  elementToTriggerDownload.click()
         
  document.body.removeChild(elementToTriggerDownload)
});
```

The code works well in case of .txt files, for example but it fails in case of photos. When I try to download photos, I see that the data is received properly from the function, but the file that is downloaded cannot be opened and it is bigger that the original one (I see that after download on disk).

I guess that I do not "construct" the file well and I miss something important, but I am not sure what.
I have done tests with postman, called the function and the images are displayed fine.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!